# Modem Throws me out of Wifi Network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a Cisco Router. At any point of time no more than 4 people can be connect to the network. And it keeps kicking me out of the wifi. If i disconnect and reconnect again am back on the network. IS there any thing i need to configure so that this does not happen ?

Comment: Model of router?  DHCP Scope?

Comment: Are you using DHCP? If you have access to the router’s configuration, check the DHCP settings. Perhaps the router’s built-in DHCP server is configured to only support hand out up to four IP addresses.

Comment: am sorry guys. can u please tell me how to check it ?

Comment: Provide the exact model and we can help